# shell init issue when click tab, what's wrong with getcwd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pwd, getcwd

once i click Tab on bash, the error message will appear, what's wrong?

```
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
symlink-hook: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
```

sometimes, the error message is:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No s uch file or directory
```

how to solve shell init problem?

Answer (score 301):

This usually occurs when your current directory does not exist anymore. Most likely, from another terminal you remove that directory (from within a script or whatever). To get rid of this, in case your current directory was recreated in the meantime, just `cd` to another (existing) directory and then `cd` back; the simplest would be: `cd; cd -`.

Comment: i don't think my dir is not exist, not someone have recreated it, i am in /root... so the issue maybe a bit different as your saying...

Comment: can you check your HOME env variable ? `echo $HOME`; if that points to an unexisting location, that't it.

Comment: (i use shell in tmux)Tab works well some times, but sometimes when i create new tab with tmux, press Tab, and this error appears, i don't know what happened:(

Comment: @kevinarpe That's good to know, thanks! I always thought it was smart enough to do nothing on `cd .`

Comment: @kevinarpe, I'd strongly suggest `cd "$PWD"` rather than `cd $(pwd)`; the latter is both inefficient (spawning a subshell) and buggy (string-splitting and glob-expanding the directory name, so it fails on directories with spaces, directories whose names contain wildcards that successfully match anything else on disk, and other such "fun" cases).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point.  (1) I don't know why I forgot to wrap with double quotes.  (2) If `PWD` is guarantee to be defined, then it is certainly faster than called `pwd` from a subshell.  My original comment should have read: As a trick: `cd `. or `cd "$(pwd)"` will also work.

Comment: @kevinarpe, yes, `$PWD` is guaranteed by POSIX to be defined. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Answer (score 69):

Just change the directory to another one and come back. Probably that one has been deleted or moved.

Answer (score 7):

By chance, is this occurring on a directory using OverlayFS (or some other special file system type)?

I just had this issue where my cross-compiled version of bash would use an internal implementation of `getcwd` which has issues with OverlayFS. I found information about this here:

> It seems that this can be traced to an internal implementation of
>   getcwd() in bash. When cross-compiled, it can't check for getcwd() use
>   of malloc, so it is cautious and sets GETCWD_BROKEN and uses an
>   internal implementation of getcwd(). This internal implementation
>   doesn't seem to work well with OverlayFS.
>
> http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.embedded.yocto.general/25204

You can configure and rebuild bash with `bash_cv_getcwd_malloc=yes` (if you're actually building bash and your C library does malloc a getcwd call).

Comment: I was able to fix my error by doing the full library updates

Answer (score 6):

Yes, cd; and cd - would work.
The reason It can see is that, directory is being deleted from any other terminal or any other program and recreate it. So i-node entry is modified so program can not access old i-node entry.

Comment: I was able to fix it on ubuntu 14 by doing the full library updates here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04